# How to pluck unique relationships from query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to pluck unique set of relation which are present in query set of models. I have model User with table 'users' and model Role with table 'roles', User hasMany Role.

```
//User.php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

//Role.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

I managed it using collections, but it needs to run such a big query, what slowing whole request

```
//Controller
...
$users = User::query()->someChainOfScopes();
$uniqueRoles = $users->get()->pluck('roles')->flatten(1)->unique('id')->values();
...
```

This code returns collection which I need, but I would like to implement it using query builder to pluck unique roles for speed improvement

Comment: Can you post what you expect the end result to look like

Comment: I expect to get collection of roles like when executing Role::find([1,2,3]).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you could do this using Laravel,

Joins could be an option to join the 2 tables in a `DB::table()` query and then find the users using the parameters you require and return the role_id.

To speed up users

```
$user_ids = DB::table('users')->select('id')->someChainOfScopes()->get();
```

The chained scopes you will have to change to standard where functions etc.

Then use this array to query the role_user table direct

```
$role_ids = DB::table('role_user')
                ->select('role_id')
                ->whereIn('user_id', $user_ids)
                ->distinct()
                ->get();
```

The problem with collections and plucking from collections is it has to iterate over the whole array of objects just to pull a field out. When that is a large collection then iis very costly.

I've not tested but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Tried your idea and got increasing of speed, but $users->pluck('id') is also fetching large amount of data to ram. It works with current amount of users but can cause memory overflow when database will contain more users

Comment: I've updated again as I cant remember if you can do selects on eloquent models.  So again we just use the DB::table method.   I think this is probably marginally better performance wise anyway.